# In Spring-boot-oauth, how come Google is able to hit my local "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google" callback end-point?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using spring security to authenticate with Google. I am following this: https://github.com/kriscfoster/SpringOAuth2Demo. Please see below for the main pieces of the logic to enable oauth2login. Everything is working as expected.

I do see - for Google authentication, Spring-boot-oauth client while invoking Google end-point (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth), passing my spring-boot app's local end-point: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google as redirect URI. And Google in-return after authentication passing **authroization_code** to the redirect URI (in this case: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google).

**Question**

1. This may be basic, but how come Google is able to hit my localhost endpoint? (the redirect URI - documentation says - The redirect URI is the path in the application that the end-user’s user-agent is redirected back to after they have authenticated with Google. But I don't know what it means by **end-user’s user-agent is redirected back to**. Looks like it does mean, Google is not calling back **localhost**  - rather something to do with browser/http protocol.
2. Can someone please point me to the code reference that's serving the redirect URI (localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google)?

   ```
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<my client ID>
    spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<my client secret>
   ```

   **// Spring security configuration**

   ```
    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(new String[]{"/", "/not-restricted"}).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
   ```

**// POM dependencies**

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: 1) Google doesn't call your URL, it is your (user's) browser.

Comment: 2) See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2Client-client-registration

Comment: See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.2